# SQL full text search behavior on numeric values

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with about 200 million records. One of the columns is defined as varchar(100) and it's included in a full text index. Most of the values are numeric. Only few are not numeric.
The problem is that it's not working well. For example if a row contains the value '123456789' and i look for '567', it's not returning this row. It will only return rows where the value is exactly '567'.
What am I doing wrong?

sql server 2012.

Thanks.

Comment: show us the query you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full text search doesn't support leading wildcards

In my setup, these return the same

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[somelogtable]
  where CONTAINS (logmessage, N'28400')

SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[somelogtable]
  where CONTAINS (logmessage, N'"2840*"')
```

This gives zero rows

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[somelogtable]
  where CONTAINS (logmessage, N'"*840*"')
```

You'll have to use LIKE or some [fancy trigram approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161328/using-fulltext-search-to-find-a-sequence-of-digits)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are using a wrong tool since Full-text queries perform [linguistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistics) searches and it seems like you want to use simple "like" condition.

If you want to get a solution to your needs then you can post DDL+DML+'desired result'

Answer (score -1):

99% You're missing `%` after and before the string you search in the `LIKE` clause.
es:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE att LIKE '66'
```

is the same as as using `WHERE att = '66'`

if you write:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE att LIKE '%66%'
```

will return you all the lines containing 2 'sixes' one after other

Comment: I'm not using like. I'm using full text search.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
....your_query.... LIKE '567%' ;
```

This will return all the rows that have a number 567 in the beginning, end or in between somewhere.

Comment: I'm not using like. I'm using full text search.

Comment: So, to do Full Text Search, I found the reference here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017, you can do this: 

....your_query.... CONTAINS(variable,'567')